# Lexer Outputs "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes" in Python. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, lexer

I am sorry if this is only a dumb mistake, because I have little experience with Python, or programming at all. `pickle.dump(code, output)`does not like the arguments I am giving it. How do I resolve this?

Here is the piece of sample code that outputs my file to lexer_output.txt:

```
global output
output = open ("C:\\Users\Asher\Documents\BUSlang\lexer_output", "w")
pickle.dump(code, output)
```

The error is

```
"TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes"
```

The variable `code` is defined earlier in the script at `code=meta.read()`. There were no other errors.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? What is `meta`?

Comment: I am using Python 3.5. Why do you ask?

Comment: `meta` was declared-ish in `with open ("C:\\Users\Asher\Documents\BUSlang\code.txt", "r") as meta:`, `code` was declared in its scope, if I am using the word correctly.

Comment: Should I use `"r+"` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is not very helpful. After some trial and error I got it to work with

```
output = open("C:\\Users\Asher\Documents\BUSlang\lexer_output", "wb")
```

i.e. the output file you want to write to must be opened in binary mode.

Another note: I'm not sure why you are using `global output`, in your sample code it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

From [`pickle.dump()` docs](https://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump):

> The file argument must have a `write()` method that accepts a single
>   `bytes` argument.

`"w"` file mode implies that `write()` accepts `str` objects, not `bytes`, pass `"wb"` instead.

You should have passed a binary file instead of the file opened in the text mode.